# Flutter: Mobile webapp responsive UI render fine on mobile browser apps but not on in-app webview

Tags: flutter, flutterwebviewplugin

Using `webview_flutter` package for showing a webview inside my application. The web page is made responsive to mobile views as well and it's loading without any issue on mobile browsers like chrome, firefox, etc. But when I'm loading the same page through my webview, it's actually not rendering as a responsive layout. It's just trying to fit whatever there on a full webpage to mobile not following any responsiveness.

```
    WebView(
           initialUrl: myHttpsUrl,
           javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
           javascriptChannels: <JavascriptChannel>[
              _eventChannel(context),
           ].toSet(),
           gestureNavigationEnabled: false,
           onPageStarted: _pageStarted,
           onPageFinished: _pageFinished,
    ),
```

The same behavior observed in Android and iOS platforms.

Edit: The webpage is setting viewport meta like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Do you have a `viewport` meta set in your HTML?

Comment: Edited the question with viewport meta details.

Comment: Hi, did u get any work around on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

must add this meta head to html file

```html
<head><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width,initial-scale=1\" /></head>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).